# Persistent Lua environment

Tags: luatex

I'm using luacode* but each separate block does not remember the state of any others.  Is there any way to remedy this? I'd like to move some large calculations in to tables at the start of the program and reference them.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the problem.  Constructing a simple test document myself, I could access results from previous blocks without problem.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: Use global variables.

Lua blocks in LuaTeX do actually preserve their state, especially they run with the same environment (meaning they see the same global variables except if you do something special). They do not have the same *local variable* through. They can be seen like different files which are loaded from the same Lua program one after another. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
  local l_table = "I am local and not visible from other blocks"
  glostr = "I am a global string and can be read anywhere in the document"
\end{luacode*}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  assert(l_table == nil, "l_table should not be defined anymore because it was defined local")
  tex.sprint(glostr) -- On the other hand, glostr was global, so it is still visible
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

Comment: It's not preserving functions. When I define a function I cannot call it from another block. I'm pretty sure lua functions are global by default... I can define a function variable and maybe that will work...